# Reduce a white gap between two <hr> tags

Tags: html

I have the following menu [image: menu]

The two lines are both 'hr' tags and the menu is a div containing a ul.  I have been googling for a while now and trying adjusting the css with margin and padding but I want to reduce the white space between the lines and the text bringing them closer to the text.

HTML:

```html
<hr id="header_line"/>
<div id="menu_bar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Add new Form</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">View old forms</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Site Administration</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<hr id="under_menu_line"/>
```

CSS:

```css
#menu_bar ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:0px;
}

#menu_bar ul li {
    display:inline;
    padding-left:10px;
}

#menu_bar ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:Black;
    font-family:Century Gothic;
    font-size:12pt;
}

#menu_bar ul li a:hover {
    color:#007C5A;
}

#header_line {
    margin-top:5px;
}

#under_menu_line {
    margin-top:5px;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: in regards to what css I tried i tried adjusting margin-top/bottom and the same with padding on all 3 elements

Comment: You could put a negative top and bottom `margin` on `#menu_bar`, but that's a bit hackish. Madara's answer is the better option, though, as it is semantically correct.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best solution would be to drop the `<hr>`s, and use `border-top` and `border-bottom` in conjunction with `padding` on the div.

`<hr>` should be used as a horizontal rule. For instance, a hard separation of paragraphs or a long break. And not as a visual element.

Comment: Thanks I should of done this from the start, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 10):

Just like with any other element, the `<hr>` is controlled by CSS.  The space you want to control is just the margin.  This is the default from Firefox:

```
hr {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-float-edge: margin-box;
    border: 1px inset;
    color: gray;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 0.5em auto;
}
```

So, the following will make the space 0.1em instead of 0.5em:

```
hr { margin: 0.1em auto; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this and tell me if this is what you wanted.

```css
#header_line { margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:-10px;} 
#under_menu_line { margin-top:-10px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```css
#header_line{
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

#under_menu_line{
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

Comment: Why should he use your answer? Please add more details to your answer :-)